# How to remove NAs in the results of a tapply function from a subset of data

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset containing several variables in columns and 16 groups (to simplify it, I´d say, I have 8 groups) for different soils and transects. I wish to make barplots with the mean of every group. But P_ero and P_upsl, as well as ZT_ero and ZT_upls and so on should be shown beside in the graph.
My data (df) looks like that: (carbon and nitrogen content for diffrent soils (e.g. P-Ploughing, ZT-zero tillage)).

```
name    N_cont  C_cont  group
P_ero   1,064   8,380   1
P_ero   0,961   8,086   1
P_ero   0,977   8,331   1
ZT_ero  1,767   17,443  2
ZT_ero  1,802   18,264  2
ZT_ero  2,083   20,112  2
Ms_ero  1,547   14,380  3
Ms_ero  1,566   15,313  3
Ms_ero  1,505   14,760  3
Md_ero  1,512   14,303  4
Md_ero  1,656   15,331  4
Md_ero  1,500   13,788  4
P_upsl  1,121   10,581  5
P_upsl  1,159   10,460  5
P_upsl  1,223   10,171  5
ZT_upsl 1,962   20,656  6
ZT_upsl 1,784   16,780  6
ZT_upsl 1,720   17,482  6
Ms_upsl 1,578   16,228  7
Ms_upsl 1,634   15,331  7
Ms_upsl 1,394   13,419  7
Md_upsl 1,286   11,824  8
Md_upsl 1,241   11,452  8
Md_upsl 1,317   11,932  8
```

I made subsets of data for each soil, like that (for Ploughing):

```
P<-df[grepl("(P)", df$group), ]; P
```

and then the means of carbon-content

```
tapply(X=P$C_cont,INDEX = P$name,FUN = mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I actually just want the means of the groups with an "P" in the column "name", but as result I get all the other groups with NAs:

```
   P_ero    ZT_ero    Ms_ero    Md_ero    P_upsl   ZT_upsl 
  8.265667      NA        NA        NA 10.404000        NA 
  Ms_upsl   Md_upsl   
      NA         NA
```

So I can`t make barplots with NAs.
Does anybody know, how this might work?

Comment: this should drop the unused factor levels: `tapply(X=P$C_cont, INDEX = factor(P$name),FUN = mean,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: factor(P$name) works. FYI: the df$group in the grepl should be df$name

Comment: This is a great easy way to complete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your `tapply` to a value, say `x`, then `x[!is.na(x)]` does the job.

Comment: `with(df[grepl("P", df$name), ], tapply(C_cont, name, mean, na.rm=TRUE))` avoids `P` by the way.

Comment: Using with retains the factor levels from name.It will still produce the NA values

Comment: @DAV sure. that's just to avoid the `P` assignation .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df$name <- as.character(df$name)
P<-df[grepl("(P)", df$group), ]; P
tapply(X=P$C_cont,INDEX = P$name,FUN = mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

My guess is that your `df$name` is a `vector` of `factor`. But it is difficult to test without actual data.